# python generate sublist with offset and condition

Tags: python, list, generator

Hey I'm trying to generate sublists of a list. For example I've a list like this:
`l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`

I want to split them in sublists with the length of 4. But to first element is the same like the last element from the previous list AND like I said it must have the length of 4. Like this:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [4,5,6,7]
l3 = [7,8,9,10] 
l4 = [10, 11, 12] <-- should be ignored
```

Does someone has an idea?! I'm thinking about an generator but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: You sure have tried something. Show it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple but flexible generator implementation:

```
def overlapping_sublists(l, n, overlap=1, start=0):          
    while start <= len(l) - n:
        yield l[start:start+n]
        start += n - overlap
```

Example usage:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> list(overlapping_sublists(l, 4))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> list(overlapping_sublists(l, 4, 2, 3))
[[4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = []
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
for i in range(0, len(l)-3, 3):
    a.append(l[i:i+4])
```

will give `a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 10]]`

or you can use as a list comprehension:

```
[l[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(l)-3, 3)]
```

Comment: That's a list comprehension, not a generator.

Comment: @tobias_k Changing `[` to `(` makes it a generator expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
print([l[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 10], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Only sublists of length 4:

```
print([m for m in [l[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)] if len(m) == 4])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Using generators:

```
for n in (m for m in (l[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)) if len(m) == 4):
    print(n)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[7, 8, 9, 10]
```